# JCombobox value retrieve from MySql Data base

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jcombobox

I use the following code for retrieve the data from my Sql DB.retrieve StudName and StudId from Data Base.StudName will display JComboBox.But how to show the StudId in Messagebox.If I select the first record in combo box means i need the corresponding Id in Message box.how to do this?
 thanks in Advance

```
public class FrmeA extends javax.swing.JFrame  {

          FrmA1 f1=new FrmA1();
          Statement TmpFlxTSt=null;
          ResultSet TmpFlxTRs=null;
          GContnStr GCS=new GContnStr();

        public FrmeA() {
             initComponents();
        }
    public void combo(){

         try{
                    GCS.GContnStr();
                    TmpFlxTSt= GCS.GCotnStr.createStatement();
                    String select = "Select StudId,StudName from studentmaster";
                    TmpFlxTRs = TmpFlxTSt.executeQuery(select);
                      while(TmpFlxTRs.next()){
                       cbx.addItem(TmpFlxTRs.getString("StudName"));
                       Object comboitem=cbx.getSelectedItem();

                   }
                        TmpFlxTRs.close();
                        TmpFlxTSt.close();
            }
               catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println(e);

        }

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JCombobox value retrieve from My Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698450/jcombobox-value-retrieve-from-my-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> retrieve StudName and StudId from Data Base.StudName will display JComboBox.But how to show the StudId in Messagebox.

You can use a JOptionPane for this purpose, something like this would serve,

```
String message = TmpFlxTRs.getString("StudId");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, message);
```

> If I select the first record in combo box means i need the corresponding Id in Message box.how to do this?

Configure an actionlistener for this purpose or an ItenStateChanged listener would be better.

Comment: final String addid=TmpFlxTRs.getString("StudId");
                                          
                      cbx.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
                          System.out.println(addid);
                           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+addid);
         }
  }); If I use ItemStateChanged like this I got all Student Id displayed.but how can i show the correct Id for the clicked name

Comment: @javabeginner I'm not exactly sure what you are speaking :( can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ? and btw, try this way, combobox.getselectedItem will return you the Student name, use this to query the db, like SELECT StudID from DB where StudName=combobox.getselectedItem.toString() ,In that case you'l have only one result. cheers.

Comment: @javabeginner hope you didnt copy paste the query :) whats the error?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Student` class, with an ID and a name, and a `toString()` method which returns the name, and add instances of `Student` to the combo box instead of adding the names. The `getSelectedItem()` method will return a `Student`, and you'll just have to call `getId()` to get its ID.